# Регулярное выражение: текст после шаблона

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, re

Задача: Есть тест, его нужно разбить по группам.
Пример: "(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. (2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. (3) Тест письма: ..."

Вопрос: Как мне получить что-то такое:
(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. \n
(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. \n
(3) Тест письма: ... \n

Это всё, что пока у меня получилось:

```py
value = "(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. (2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. (3) Тест письма: ..."

reg = re.findall('\(\d\)', value)
>>>['(1)', '(2)', '(3)']
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Можно без регулярных выражений (если нет жесткого ограничения условия задачи):

```
text = '(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. (2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. (3) Тест письма: ... (4) Так, давайте. Нам нужно сделать - это !'

text_split = [f'({i}\n' for i in text.split('(')[1:]]
```

в итоге:

```
>>> text_split
[
    '(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. \n', 
    '(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. \n', 
    '(3) Тест письма: ... \n', 
    '(4) Так, давайте. Нам нужно сделать - это !\n'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так :

```
    import re
    text = "(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. (2) После создания задачи Вам 
    нужно написать письмо. (3) Тест письма: ..."
    split_regex = re.compile(r'[.|!|?|…]')
    sentences = filter(lambda t: t, [t.strip() for t in split_regex.split(text)])
    for s in sentences:
        print(s)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ ! Только будет проблема с такими примерами: (4) Так, давайте. Нам нужно сделать - это ! или вот это. (5)

Answer (score 0):

**Если в тексте не ожидается скобок**, а только в заголовке, то можно ориентироваться на открывающую скобку и указать, что после заголовка может быть любой текст, кроме скобки:

```
reg = re.findall('\(\d\)[^(]*', value)
```

Содержимое `reg`:

```
['(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. ', '(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. ', '(3) Тест письма: ...']
```

Шаблон `[^(]*` означает "любое количество любых символов, кроме `(`"

**Другой вариант** - используя `re.split`, разбить строку по шаблону, а потом склеить куски обратно:

```
reg = re.split('(\(\d\))', value)
reg = [a+b for a,b in zip(reg[1::2],reg[2::2])]
```

Значение `reg`:

```
['(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. ', '(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. ', '(3) Тест письма: ...']
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый оптимальный способ — искать текст от числа в скобках до следующего числа в скобках или конца строки:

```py
import re
value = "(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу. \
(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо. (3) Тест письма: ..."
print( re.findall(r'\(\d+\).*?(?=\s*(?:\(\d+\)|$))', value) )
# [
#    '(1) Для начала Вам нужно создать задачу.',
#    '(2) После создания задачи Вам нужно написать письмо.',
#    '(3) Тест письма: ...'
# ]
```

См. [пример кода в Python](https://ideone.com/EtoOfF).

**Подробности**

- `\(\d+\)` - `(`, одно и более цифр и `)`
- `.*?` - ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `(?=\s*(?:\(\d+\)|$))` - до первого вхождения следующей последовательности символов:

  - `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
  - `(?:\(\d+\)|$)` - или `(`, одно и более цифр и `)`, или конец строки.

Если в совпадениях присутствуют переводы строки, добавьте модификатор `re.S` / `re.DOTALL`, `re.findall(r'\(\d+\).*?(?=\s*(?:\(\d+\)|$))', value, re.DOTALL)`.

Если вы хотите проверить, есть ли точка/восклицательный (вопросительный) знак перед числом в скобках, испраьте шаблон на `r'\(\d+\).*?[.?!](?=\s*(?:\(\d+\)|$))'`.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/6lAKYB/3).